# Access Denied when Remotely Accessing SSIS SQL Server Integration Services

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Mystery of the Day:

I have two users who access SQL Server Integration Services remotely from their local machines.  User 1 successfully connects using the Integration Service server type in SSMS.  User 2 gets this error:

[image: access denied]

Note that 2005 is mentioned in the error, tho user 2 does not have 2005 installed.  Both User 2 and the server are running 2014.  Both users have the same persmissions on the remote server, and both are admins on the server.  User 2 also gets this error when connecting to SSIS on the server, however, she is able to connect successfully when running SSMS as an administrator on the server.  Here are some things that we've already tried:

Confirmed that User 2 is using a lower version of SQL than the version on the server.
Matched both users SSMS permissions to each other.
Added User 2 to the server's DCOM.
Restarted SSIS service on the server.
And this:

[image: steps tried]

We suspect there may be a version issue between local and remote installations, but not sure what to check in that regard.  There many similar posts to our issue, but we have combed through without success.  Hoping someone can help here.

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe it's Windows authentication mode change it

Comment: Are the users running the same version of SSMS? The latest (18.4) was release on Nov 4, 2019. You don't need to have SQL Server installed to connect to a remote server, but you definitely should have the latest version of SSMS, regardless of which version of SQL Server you're connecting to. Are one or both users running their local copies of SSMS in admin mode? Has User 2 ever been able to connect remotely? Can User 2 connect with her credentials while sitting at User 1's workstation, and vice-versa?

Answer (score 1):

I changed the default logon of the SQL Server Integration Services 15.0 service to be the NT account on the VM I was given and was able to connect to Integration Services after a service restart.